Permission issues with Docker and users made for containers
I am new to Docker, but I try to learn fast. I noticed how important it was to secure my containers and my computer from root escalation, so I wanted to run my containers with specific users, each one being attributed to one container.
Sadly, I got several issues after that and because I don't know that much how Docker internally works, I either got these containers' WebUIs unaccessible or outputs like this using docker container logs :
[FATAL tini (7)] exec /entrypoint.sh failed: Permission denied
error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

and other kinds of "permission denied"-like outputs. Sometimes, the container keeps restarting.
Here is my containers' data folders. I am running Openmediavault so consider the docker folder as the one that contains the compose files, data and backups. My picky side putted me to remove any permissions to other users than the one attributed to the service/container.
drwxrws---+ 14 root           torrent        4096 26 oct.  13:32 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 root           root           4096 19 oct.  18:49 ..
drwxrws---   5 calibre        calibre        4096 19 oct.  14:57 calibre
drwxrws---+  6 root           docker         4096 12 oct.  14:22 docker
drwxrws---   7 jellyfin       jellyfin       4096 26 oct.  17:37 jellyfin
drwxr-s---   4 root           users          4096 12 oct.  18:38 jellystat
drwxrws---   4 navidrome      navidrome      4096 13 oct.  09:45 navidrome
drwxrws---+  6 photoprism     photoprism     4096 12 oct.  14:40 photoprism
drwxrws---   3 caldav         caldav         4096 26 oct.  01:53 radicale
drwxrws---   2 root           users          4096 26 oct.  18:27 scripts
drwxrws---   3 titlecardmaker titlecardmaker 4096 26 oct.  02:25 titlecardmaker
drwxrws---   8 video-dl       video-dl       4096 26 oct.  13:57 video-dl

What's going wrong in my install? It's definitely related to my permissions tweakenings but I am not sure what exactly. I tried to audit the container folders to get a bit of a hint but it wouldn't give me interesting enough info.
